# Lusztig's $h$-function of a dihedral group

Tags: representation-theory, coxeter-groups

Following the notations in [Hecke algebras with unequal parameters](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0208154v2), let $(W,S,L)$ be a weighted Coxeter system, and $H$ be the corresponding Hecke algebra with $\{c_w |w \in W\}$ the Kazhdan-Lusztig basis of $H$. The $h$-polynoimal is defined in Section 13.1 as

> $$c_xc_y = \sum_{z \in W}h_{x,y,z}c_z.$$

Now let $W$ be dihedral, with $S=\{\mathbf 1,\mathbf 2\}$, and the order of $\mathbf 1\mathbf 2$ is an even integer $m$. The weight function $L$ satisfies $L(\mathbf 1) = L_1$, $L(\mathbf 2) =L_2$ and $L_1<L_2$.

What I would like to know is $h_{x,y,z}$ for $x,y,z \in W$ , especially when $z=w_0$,the longest element in $W$. Lusztig has done some calculation of $h$-function in dihedral group in Sections 13.10 and 13.11. But I am wondering if there is a complete list of $h$ in this case. Thanks.